# DOM manipulation with loop or inside new Constructor?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have couple of `<div>` with `data-bg-color` attribute. I have created a function that get all of them using `querySelectorAll` and set a background color according the value in `data-bg-color`. I am quite new in a Constructor approach in JS, so my question is: What is the better way to manipulate these elements?

There are two alternatives:

One is to get all elements at once and loop through them in the constructor:

```
var Background = function (selector) {
    this.elements = (selector) ? document.querySelectorAll(selector) : document.querySelectorAll("[data-bg-color]");
    if(this.elements.length) this.setColor();
};

Background.prototype.setColor = function () {
    Array.from(this.elements, function (element) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = element.getAttribute("data-bg-color");
    });
};

var bg = new Background();
```

Two, is to create new Constructors in the loop for every data-bg-color element:

```
var Background = function (element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.setColor();
};

Background.prototype.setColor = function () {
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = this.element.getAttribute("data-bg-color");
};

for( var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll("[data-bg-color]").length; i++ ){
    new Background( document.querySelectorAll("[data-bg-color]")[i] );
}
```

In the first case I want to simply the process so only `new Background()` is required. It automatically get all `data-bg-color` elements on the page and set them a color. Also if, the user wants to target only desired element he can done it using `new Background("#modal [data-bg-color]")`.

This rather a helper function, so maybe the prototype approach is not good for this, but I wanted to avoid spaghetti code if this gets bigger.

Comment: Definitely avoid the second option - constructors should not be used for side effects only, use a plain function instead IMO. First option looks OK-ish if you're going to be using the `bg.elements` later

Comment: Are you doing anything with `bg` later? In the second version, you evidently don't: the returned constructed object is not retained (and thus garbage collected).

Comment: No, the `bg` variable will not be used later. It seems that better solution is plain function as @CertainPerformance mentioned

Answer (score 1):

It seems (at least from the second version) that you don't have a use for the `Background` instance(s), once they are constructed. The value returned by `new Background` is not used (and eventually garbage collected), and so it seems overkill to even define a constructor for this task.

Constructors are better suited for when you need to keep state and need methods that can be invoked later on that state.

In this case however I would just stick with a simple function that does the job:

```
function applyBackground(selector = "[data-bg-color]") {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector), 
               elem => elem.style.backgroundColor = elem.getAttribute("data-bg-color"));
}
```

Note also the use of a default value for the argument. The use of an arrow function here is debatable; I just provide it as alternative.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it's better solution as this will run only on page load. And also the function can be called later.